# Javascript: From JSON array of strings in the form of key:value to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, key-value

say that I receive this JSON array from an API call.

```
[
  "{'apple': 'enabled'}",
  "{'banana': 'disabled'}"
]
```

How do I transform it into this:

```
[
  {
    label: 'apple',
    value: 'enabled'
  },
  {
    label: 'banana',
    value: 'disabled'
  }
]
```

The number of fields and the values are of course variable.

With JSON5.parse() I can transform it into this:

```
[
  {
    apple: 'enabled',
  },
  {
    banana: 'disabled'
  }
]
```

But this is still not what I need.

How can I achieve the transformation I need, without hacky workarounds that might change the values inside?

Thank you

Comment: You could iterate over all entries of that first array, parse each seperately and then extract the label and the value with `Object.keys()`.

Comment: @Alexander I tried that, but that creates an array of arrays containing one item each

Comment: Object.keys() returns all keys of an object, so of course its an array. But you know that in your usecase its always just one element, namely "label".

Comment: True, I managed to make it work like this:
`data.map(el=>{return{label: Object.keys(JSON5.parse(el))[0],value: Object.values(JSON5.parse(el))[0] }})`

Comment: Yep, thats a very convoluted but JSic way to do it :D

Comment: Yeah I fixed it up and added it as a possible answer as well :D

Answer (score 2):

```
const apiArray = [
  "{'apple': 'enabled'}",
  "{'banana': 'disabled'}"
];

const returnArray = [];

for (const element of apiArray) {
  const parsedObj = JSON.parse(element);
  const label = Object.keys(element)[0];
  const value = parsedObj[label];

  returnArray.push({"label": label, "value": value});
}
```

This inspects every element of the initial array on its own and extracts the label and the value. These then get pushed into the returnArray in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with this:
(Thanks @Alexander)

```
data.map(el=>{
  const parsed = JSON5.parse(el)
  return{
    label: Object.keys(parsed)[0],
    value: Object.values(parsed)[0] 
  }
})
```

However, it is not very clean.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var newArr = [];
apiArray.forEach((element) => {
  let obj = JSON.parse(element.replaceAll("'", '"'));
  newArr.push({ label: Object.keys(obj)[0], value: Object.values(obj)[0] });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try something like this :

```
myArray.map((data) => {
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  return {
    label: Object.keys(parsedData).join(),
    value: Object.values(parsedData).join(),
  };
});
```

Output :

```
[{
    "label": "apple",
    "value": "enabled"
},
{
    "label": "banana",
    "value": "disabled"
}]
```